# What's Relay operation name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, relayjs, relay

I am learning Relay library for GraphQL in React app.
I did everything as in official docs.
My `/project/resources/js/schema.graphql` has:

```
type usersPagination {
  """List of items on the current page"""
  data: [Users]

  """Number of total items selected by the query"""
  total: Int!

  """Number of items returned per page"""
  per_page: Int!

  """Current page of the cursor"""
  current_page: Int!

  """Number of the first item returned"""
  from: Int

  """Number of the last item returned"""
  to: Int
}
```

In my React `/project/resources/js/components/main/Table.js` I try to make query:

```
<QueryRenderer
    environment={environment}
    query={graphql`
        query usersPaginationQuery {
            data {
                Users
            }
        }
    `}
    render={({error, props}) => {
        if(error) {
            return <div>Error!</div>
        }
        if(!props) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>
        }

        return <div>User: {props.users.data.id}</div>;
    }}
/>
```

Then I run `npm run relay` to compile it but it throws me an error:

> Parse error: Error: RelayFindGraphQLTags: Operation names in graphql
>   tags must be prefixed with the module name and end in "Mutation",
>   "Query", or "Subscription". Got `usersPaginationQuery` in module
>   `Table`. in "components/main/Table.js"

For me it's nonsense, bcz my query name is exact as `module name + "Query"` keyword.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: What's the name of the file where this code is located?

Comment: I updated code. @DanielRearden

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/en/query-renderer.html):

> Note: To enable compatibility mode, relay-compiler enforces the query to be named as Query.

This is also outlind in [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1718). If your file is named `Table.js`, then your operation should be `TableQuery`.

Comment: Small progress, can you write how should my query looks for `usersPagination` schema?

Comment: I am receiving `Unknown field 'data' on type 'Query'.`

Comment: That doesn't really relate to your original question and should be a separate post. You can only query fields that exist in your schema, and apparently `data` does not.

Answer (score 1):

In GraphQL, the *operation name* is a name immediately after the `query` or `mutation` keyword and before the first open brace.  It is an arbitrary caller-provided name and doesn't relate to anything in the schema.  The first field selection after the first open brace is a field on the `Query` or `Mutation` type.

```graphql
query OperationName {
  topLevelQuery {
    fieldOnItsType
    ... OtherFields
  }
}
```

It looks like you've tried to use the name of a top-level query field in the "operation name" slot.  Since it's getting recognized as the operation name, it's not getting executed as the top-level query, and you're tripping over Relay's rules on how it should be named:

> Operation names in graphql tags must be prefixed with the module name and end in "Mutation", "Query", or "Subscription"

The current module name is `Table` (because you're in a `Table.js` file).  So your query should probably look like

```graphql
query TableQuery {
  usersPaginationQuery {
    data {
      ... SomeFieldsOnUsers
    }
  }
}
```

You're required to list out every field on `Users` you want to select (assuming that's an object type).  I've used GraphQL [fragment](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fragments) syntax here because you don't show what's in that type, but you're not allowed to use an object type name here directly.